# How can i align a image link to the middle with css

Tags: html, css

So I have this image I'm trying to align to the middle of the web frame with my CSS file style.css but I'm not sure how to, how can I do this?

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}
h1 { 
  text-align: center; font-family: sans; color: blue;
}
p {
 text-align: center; font-family: sans; color: white;
}

a {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h1>Pages</h1>
<p><a href="html/page2.html">Page Two</a></p>
<p><a href="html/page3.html">Page Three</a></p>
  
<a href="#"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100.jpg" alt="Discord" style="width:42px;height:42px;"></a>
```

Comment: Please put some effort into googling this, there are countless tutorials available and it doesn’t seem like you tried any of the approaches. Please search for „html align image center“

Comment: i tried and first off its a link with an image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution:

```
<a href="#"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100.jpg" alt="Discord" style="width:42px;height:42px;display:block;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto"></a>
```

Comment: thank you this worked but can you explain how this works ?

Comment: One way to centre an image is to set the left and right margin to be equal which can be achieved by setting the margins to 'auto'. Do note that this only works in display:block as block elements have a width property, so the width of the "auto" can be calculated. You can learn more about display here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display

Comment: thank you for your help i understand now

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your `a` tag in a flex container.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container a img {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universe">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/69/NASA-HS201427a-HubbleUltraDeepField2014-20140603.jpg" />
  </a>
</div>
```

Alternatively you can wrap it in a grid container and place items center and set the width and height to 100vw/vh respectively.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

.container a img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universe">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/69/NASA-HS201427a-HubbleUltraDeepField2014-20140603.jpg" />
      </a>
    </div>
```

Comment: no need for a flex-container. An anchor is an inline-element. As such you could simply use `text-align`. Don't over complicate a solution if a single (and correct)property can do it.